# "error: no match for 'operator='" Making 1 vector copy to another

Tags: c++, vector, struct

So i have made a instance of a class and now I am trying to use a getter to get the vector of structs that i have.

```
  struct posesData{
double xInMeters;
double yInMeters;
double direction;
}
```

So now I have created a instance of the class rangeAndPosesFiles which loads the files and parses it into data structures IE the vector.

```
private:
  char map[50][50];
  rangeAndPoseFiles files;
  vector<posesData> poses;
  int amountOfValidPoints;
  int discoveredItems[41][8];

public:
 robotAndEnviroment(){
  amountOfValidPoints = 0;
  mapFill();
  poses = files.getPosesData();
  derp();
}
```

So as you can see this line "poses = files.getPosesData();" This is where the error is being generated.

```
    central:~/cpp $ clear && g++ -g -W -Wall -Wextra -pedantic  -std=c++11 Main.cpp -o main
Main.cpp: In constructor 'robotAndEnviroment::robotAndEnviroment()':
Main.cpp:33:9: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'std::vector<robotAndEnviroment::posesData>' and 'std::vector<rangeAndPoseFiles::posesData>')
   poses = files.getPosesData();
         ^
Main.cpp:33:9: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/vector:69:0,
                 from Main.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/bits/vector.tcc:167:5: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = robotAndEnviroment::$osesData; _Alloc = std::allocator<robotAndEnviroment::posesData>]
     vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::
     ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/bits/vector.tcc:167:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<rangeAndPoseFiles::posesData>' to 'const std::vector<robotAndEnviroment:$posesData>&'
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/vector:64:0,
                 from Main.cpp:2:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_vector.h:448:7: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&&) [with _Tp = robotAndEnviroment::pos$sData; _Alloc = std::allocator<robotAndEnviroment::posesData>]
       operator=(vector&& __x) noexcept(_Alloc_traits::_S_nothrow_move())
       ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_vector.h:448:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<rangeAndPoseFiles::posesData>' to 'std::vector<robotAndEnviroment::pos$sData>&&'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_vector.h:470:7: note: std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>& std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator=(std::initializer_list<_Tp>) [with _Tp = robotAndEnviroment::pos$sData; _Alloc = std::allocator<robotAndEnviroment::posesData>]
       operator=(initializer_list<value_type> __l)
       ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.9.3/include/g++-v4/bits/stl_vector.h:470:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::vector<rangeAndPoseFiles::posesData>' to 'std::initializer_list<robotAndEnvir$ment::posesData>'
central:~/cpp $
```

I just want to get the vector from the rangeAndPoseFiles class and copy it to the RobotAndEviroment class But i get the error, how come?

Comment: Note that one is `vector<robotAndEnviroment::posesData>` and the other is `std::vector<rangeAndPoseFiles::posesData>`, making them vectors of different types. If this `posesData` is the same between `robotAndEnviroment` and `rangeAndPoseFiles`, declare it once outside of those two.

Comment: The error message looks pretty self explanitory.  You are trying to assign a  `std::vector<rangeAndPoseFiles::posesData>` to a `std::vector<robotAndEnviroment::posesData>`.  Are you sure you have the right types?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. I'm not familiar with C++ I thought that if it had the same data type regardless of the class it would work. Anyany i fixed it now. Thanks for the help guys :)